# How to refer to database connection in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How can I call manually a PHP database function on CodeIgniter's database handler object? How to retrieve the connection (`$dbc`), or call a function like `mysql_real_escape_string($dbc, $variable)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call any mysql native function and access mysql connection id.

See [CodeIgniter User Guide](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/call_function.html)

Comment: @shababhsiddique `$this->db->conn_id` will get you the current connection in a CI context. Pulled from https://mmxgroup.net/2010/02/11/get-db-handler-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 6):

`$this->db->conn_id` will get you the current connection link object if you are in a CI context. It will return a mysqli or mysql link object that you can pass into functions like `mysql_real_escape_string` or the updated mysqli, which actually requires the link object. [Source](https://mmxgroup.net/2010/02/11/get-db-handler-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 3):

It is a better idea to use codeIgiter's functions:
    `$this->db->escape()` 
    ,`$this->db->escape_str()`
    ,`$this->db->escape_like_str()`

The function `mysql_real_escape_string()` is deprecated by now ( see: http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string ).

Instead use `mysqli_real_escape_string` or `mysqli::real_escape_string` (see for the syntax: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)