# Is it possible to use manual SQL queries in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Ive been learning codeigniter and I like their database methods. However I would prefer to write my own SQL queries. When I try to write a manual query it results in a codeigniter error.

Ive searched around if it is possible however I cant find much info on the subject. The closes Ive come to an answer [was this](https://www.quora.com/Can-you-setup-CodeIgniter-to-write-your-own-SQL-queries-instead-of-using-the-build-in-functions-A-Google-search-didnt-return-much-information).

**Question**

Is it possible to disable the build in Codeigniter database methods, and perform my own sql queries. Or run my own sql queries alongside CodeIgniter's database class?

If yes, how would I go about configuring this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe pulling the underlying PDO connection out?.. Wait this looks promising [How to refer to database connection in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273550/how-to-refer-to-database-connection-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Did you tried using the `query' method of CodeIgniter database Class?

Comment: @muecas I have but it still does not give me "total control / the flexibility I want"

Comment: What's more flexible than writing your own sql queries?

Comment: $query = $this->db->query("
SELECT name
FROM user");//put your queries here and do var_dump($query) , and please share result or error

Answer (score 4):

From https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html, you can use query method from db library.

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
        echo $row->title;
        echo $row->name;
        echo $row->body;
}
```

Comment: So I can do Joins and perform all other SQL queries within the `query` method? What about binding parameters?

Comment: Yeah, you can perform all SQL queries within query. For binding parameters, you can try like this `$this->db->query("UPDATE user SET ip_whitelist=NULL WHERE username=?", [$this->session->userdata('username')]);`

Comment: @Marilee `$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = ? AND status = ? AND author = ?";
$this->db->query($sql, array(3, 'live', 'Rick'));` bind params

Answer (score 0):

$this->db->query('selec * from your_table');

you can use like this your core query ...

Answer (score -2):

## This may help you out

`

```
$sql = "select model,varient,(select color from mtbl_colors where
        mtbl_colors.colorid=mtbl_vehicles.colorid) as color from mtbl_vehicles";
```

$sql .= " where $where_clause = ?";
 $result = $this->db->query($sql, $where_value);
`